# RDMA: how do I know if a Read request is responded after polling the CQ?

Tags: rdma

I have N qps and I will send M RDMA Read requests through the send queue in each qp.
The read request is sent by `ibv_post_send()` and the cq is polled iteratively using `ibv_poll_cq()`.

The question is, if I get some work completions (WC) after calling `ibv_poll_cq()`, how do I know the WC corresponds to which read request? I am using Reliable Connection mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send Read request through `ibv_post_send()` [you are using `ibv_send_wr`](https://www.rdmamojo.com/2013/01/26/ibv_post_send/) struct, that has 
`uint64_t wr_id;` field that you've set

> wr_id - A 64 bits value associated with this WR. If a Work Completion will be
>   generated when this Work Request ends, it will contain this value.

Then when [you do `ibv_poll_cq()`](https://www.rdmamojo.com/2013/02/15/ibv_poll_cq/) you're passing `ibv_wc` struct that will filled with

> wr_id - The 64 bits value that was associated with the corresponding
>   Work Request.

Comment: You are right. I thought this id in wr was uniquely generated by the rdma protocol, but later found out that it's user-defined so I could set it by myself.